# jquery .post can't pass the value into php for checking

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, post

I have a question in jquery - Post . when I input the email in the form, the js - jquery will pass the email into sendResetPasswordMail1.php to check email is valid or not.

but now, $.post("sendResetPasswordMail1.php",mail:email},function(resetPasswordMsg) can not work in js.

I can't find what wrong. Distress.
Could you help me please.
Many Thanks.

php

```
<!--reset Password Popup start-->
    <div class="resetPasswordLayer" id="resetPassword" tabindex="-1">
        <div class="resetPasswordLayerWall" id="resetPasswordLayerWall">
            <button type="button" class="close resetPasswordCloseButton" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
            <p><h3 class="layerTittle">Reset Password</h3></p>
            <div class="row">
                <!--<form class="form-horizontal" action="ResetPassword/sendResetPasswordMail.php" method="post" id="login-form">-->
                    <div class="form-horizontal form-group">
                        <div class="input-group">
                            <p><strong>User can retrieve the password through the mailbox</strong></p>
                            <!--<p><strong>Enter your registered e-mail, retrieve your password：</strong></p>-->
                            <p><input type="text" class="form-control" name="resetPasswordEmail" id="resetPasswordEmail" placeholder="Enter your registered e-mail, retrieve your password."><span id="chkresetPasswordMsg"></span></p>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-group">
                        <div class="input-group"><!--<div class="col-md-11 col-md-offset-1">-->
                            <p><input type="button" class="btn  btn-success" id="subSendResetPassword_btn" value="Reset"></p>
                            <!--<button type="submit" class="btn btn-success"id="subSendResetPassword_btn">Reset</button>-->
                            <span id="resetPasswordMsg"></span>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                <!--</form>-->
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <!--reset Password Popup End-->
```

js - jquery

```
$(function(){
    $("#subSendResetPassword_btn").click(function(){
        var email = $("#resetPasswordEmail").val();
        var preg = /^\w+([-+.]\w+)*@\w+([-.]\w+)*\.\w+([-.]\w+)*/; //match Email
        if(email=='' || !preg.test(email)){
            $("#chkresetPasswordMsg").html("Please fill in the correct email!");
        }else{
            $("#subSendResetPassword_btn").attr("disabled","disabled").val('Submit......').css("cursor","default");
            alert(email);
            $.post("sendResetPasswordMail1.php",{mail:email},function(resetPasswordMsg){
                if(resetPasswordMsg == ""){
                    alert("No Msg Return!");
                }

                if(resetPasswordMsg=="noRegister"){
                    $("#chkresetPasswordMsg").html("The mailbox is not registered yet！");
                    //$("#subSendResetPassword_btn").removeAttr("disabled").val('Submit').css("cursor","pointer");
                }else{
                    $(".resetPasswordLayer").html("<h3>"+resetPasswordMsg+"</h3>");
                }
            });
        }
    });
})
```

php - sendResetPasswordMail1.php

```
$email = stripslashes(trim($_POST['mail']));
$sql = "select * from user where email='$email'";
$query = mysql_query($sql);
$num = mysql_num_rows($query);
if($num==0){//The mailbox is not registered yet! Return 'noRegister'
    $resetPasswordMsg = "noRegister";
    echo $resetPasswordMsg;
    exit;   
}
```

Comment: mysql syntax is depreciated and removed from php use mysqli or pdo

Answer (score 0):

Prevent the default click event

```
$("#subSendResetPassword_btn").click(function(e){
   e.preventDefault()
});
```